# cp command doesn't overwrite, but creates new folder (second time, third, fourth, .. time it works)

Tags: cp, macintosh

I use the following command to copy a folder (named 'dist') containing a react project to my frontend folder:

```
cd apps/react-app
sudo cp -R dist ../server/frontend/client
```

The first time I run the 'cp'-command, the content of the 'dist'-folder gets copied into the 'client'-folder. I would expect that when I run this command **again**, the cp-command would overwrite the files in the 'client'-folder. This doesn't happen, instead, the 'cp'-command now creates a 'dist'-folder inside the 'client'-folder en puts all the new files in there. The 3th, 4th, ... time I run the 'cp'-command, it overwrites all the files in the 'dist'-folder, but the files from the first 'cp'-command are still in the 'client'-folder also.

How can I cp the files from the 'dist'-folder to the 'client'-folder, and whenever I run this command again, it overwrites (instead of creating a new folder)?

Comment: Does the `client` directory already exist before all of this?

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't realized this in 25 years.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `cp` overwrites.  It is idempotent.

> The first time I run the 'cp'-command, the content of the
> 'dist'-folder gets copied into the 'client'-folder.

Are you sure?  Normally, the folder itself should be copied (including its content), and indeed that is want you see in the next runs.

> How can I cp the files from the 'dist'-folder to the 'client'-folder,

With

```
cp -r dist/* client
```

Comment: `cp` is not naturally idempotent. You have to use `cp -r dist/. client` for it be so

Comment: Actually you can't copy a directory without `-r`.

Comment: Can you show an example?  The original poster seems to have one but I doubt it.

Comment: The OP's example is valid

Comment: Yes, the content of the 'dist' folder is copied into the 'client' folder the first time, not the folder itself. The second time, a 'dist' folder shows up with all that content again.

Comment: I can't reproduce it.  With zsh on my computer, `cp -R` always copy the folder, not its content.  It is confusing, just like "drinking a glass of wine".

Comment: You should provide a minimal complete example.

Comment: OK I got it.  This happens if and only if  `../server/frontend/client` does not exist before running cp.  So if you run `mkdir -p ../server/frontend/client` before `cp` then no problem.

Comment: And cp is not idempotent.

Comment: As your question was really not well written, I suggest that you write a nice concluding answer.

Comment: I realize that `rsync -r` does not have this strange behaviour of `cp -r` so you could use `rsync -r` instead of `cp -r`.

Comment: I will write a conclusion in my question tomorrow. Thanks your all of your help!